# Android - how get login user profile data for Twitter with twitter4j?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twiter4j to login into app with twitter
How can i get user email id, gender etc. with twitter4j library?

I can get username with following code,,

```
  long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
  User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
  userName = user.getName();
```